# What's wrong with this string equality comparison? (Python)

Tags: python, string, comparison

My code is for a simple hangman type game where the user is supposed to guess the a random word from a list letter by letter or guess the whole word. The comparison for when the user guesses the whole word doesn't execute. I hardcoded one of the possible random words into my code below as an example:

```
guess = "----"
letterCount = 8
letter = ""

x = 0
while letterCount > 0:
    temp1 = "word"
    letter = input("Guess a letter in the word or attempt to guess the whole word: ")
    if (len(letter) > 1):
        print ("this is the test word: word, this is letter:" + letter)
        if letter == "word":
            print ("You win!!!")
            letterCount = 0
    else:
        x = temp1.find(letter)
        while x != -1:
            x = temp1.find(letter)
            temp1 = temp1[:(x + 1)].replace(letter, '0') + temp1[(x + 1):]
            guess = guess[:(x + 1)].replace('-', letter) + guess[(x + 1):]
        print (("Your guess is now: " + guess))
    letterCount = letterCount - 1
    x = 0
```

If I guess the "word", it tells me that I guess word, it points out that I guess the word I should, but the if statement that should tell me I won never executes. Am I comparing these strings properly or is the problem something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> while letterCount > 0:
...     temp1 = "word"
...     letter = input("Guess a letter in the word or attempt to guess the whole word: ")
...     if (len(letter) > 1):
...         print ("this is the test word: word, this is letter:" + letter)
...         if letter == "word":
...             print ("You win!!!")
...             letterCount = 0
...     else:
...         x = temp1.find(letter)
...         while x != -1:
...             x = temp1.find(letter)
...             temp1 = temp1[:(x + 1)].replace(letter, '0') + temp1[(x + 1):]
...             guess = guess[:(x + 1)].replace('-', letter) + guess[(x + 1):]
...         print (("Your guess is now: " + guess))
...     letterCount = letterCount - 1
...     x = 0
...
Guess a letter in the word or attempt to guess the whole word: "word"
this is the test word: word, this is letter:word
You win!!!
>>>
```

You need to cast your input as a String for the String comparison test to work.